# invalid table name unnesting

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

I am learning to unnest in bigquery, it is my understanding the UNNEST(hits)  follows the table name, and in the where clause you define the hits.type in the WHERE clause. The query below gives the error invalid table name, however the table name is correct:

```
SELECT index, value
FROM (SELECT hits.customDimensions.index as index,
             hits.customDimensions.value as value
      FROM `60400612.ga_sessions_*`,
            UNNEST(hits) AS hits
      WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN '20190714' and '20190811'
         AND hits.type = 'customDimensions')
GROUP BY 1,2
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post the complete Error Message with the question

Comment: Query Failed
Error: Invalid table name: `60400612.ga_sessions_*` [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)].

Answer (score 0):

I am actually not sure what the scoping rules are.  However, I think it is a bad practice to use the same name.  So, just rename it to `hit`:

```
FROM 60400612.ga_sessions_* CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(hits) AS hit
WHERE  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20190714' and '20190811' AND
       hit.type = 'customDimensions'
```

Answer (score 0):

This query for example does actually work (same nesting construction i used):

```
SELECT Source, Medium, New_Users, Sessions, ((Bounces/Sessions) * 100) AS bounce_rate
FROM(SELECT trafficSource.source AS Source, TrafficSource.medium AS medium, 
COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS Users, COUNT(DISTINCT(
      CASE
        WHEN totals.newVisits = 1 THEN fullVisitorId
      ELSE
      NULL
    END
      )) AS New_Users, 
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING))) AS Sessions, sum(totals.bounces) AS Bounces
FROM
  `60400612.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE 
  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20190714' and '20190811'
  AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
  AND hits.page.hostname like 'xxx'
GROUP BY 1,2)
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```